# Getting the n-th key/value in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There's an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [url] => https://is0.Z0V.jpg
            [width] => 370
            [height] => 370
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [url] => https://is1.et/derived_pi0V_300x300.jpg
            [width] => 300
            [height] => 300
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [url] => https://is1.n100x100.jpg
            [width] => 100
            [height] => 100
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [url] => https://is1.t/dZ0V_36x36.jpg
            [width] => 36
            [height] => 36
        )

)
```

How do I only get the [2] from this foreach and insert it into this:

```
foreach($fotoSuggSizes as $fotoSuggSize100)
    {

        $image_urlSugg100[] = array("urlx100"=>$fotoSuggSize100->url);

    }
```

Comment: Insert or overwrite? What's with http://php.net/array_splice ?

Comment: ehm ... do you mean `$fotoSuggSizes[2]->url`?!

Comment: Sorry not insert, just to get !

Comment: Your question is very unclear because you have not named the array you posted or indicated how it fits into the foreach loop below it.

Comment: @andrewliu: Then why do you `foreach`? Just pick `$fotoSuggSizes[2]`.

Comment: @hakre thankyou, that would just be a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert at a specific offset in an exisitng array another array by using [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice):

```
$insert = array("urlx100"=>$fotoSuggSize100->url);
array_splice($fotoSuggSizes, 2, 0, array($insert));
```

However I'm not totally sure from your question if that is what you're looking for.

The other way round would be:

```
$image_urlSugg100[] = array("urlx100" => $fotoSuggSizes[2]->url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is following:

```
foreach($fotoSuggSizes as $n => $fotoSuggSize100)
{
   if ($n != 2) continue;
   $image_urlSugg100[] = array("urlx100"=>$fotoSuggSize100->url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the original array called `$fotoSuggSize100`?

```
$image_urlSugg100[] = array("urlx100"=>$fotoSuggSize100[2]->url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but:

```
$image_urlSugg100[] = array("urlx100"=>$fotoSuggSizes[2]->url);
```

Or, if for some reason you specifically want to use the `foreach()` method:

```
foreach ($fotoSuggSizes as $k => $v)
{
    if ($k == 2)
    {
         $image_urlSugg100[] = array("urlx100"=>$v->url);
    }
}
```